# magento homepage breaks - not fully loaded

Tags: php, magento

In my magento homepage there's a Best Seller products block. When cache is enabled this block breaks page in half and it's not fully loaded. Disabling the cache solves this issue but I have to keep it enabled for good speed.

I have spotted the exact lines that cause this issue but I can't fix it. Actually what cause this issue is redeclaring the $_product in a loop. I had to redeclare it because some product data did not update from one product to another during the loop.

This is the line that breaks the page:

**$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());**

I have enabled php error reporting and there are no php errors occuring. No fatal errors or warnings.

Removing this line solves the issue but then product data is not loaded correctly.

What should I do to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exactly the same issue,

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)
```

fails. Couldn't figure it out yet what causing that problem. No errors, nothing. It looks like PHP is out of resources and just terminates the script, but I have increased my memory_limit value to 8048M even and it did not help at all.

EDIT:

Turned out that Cart2Quote required ionCube extension to work properly. Since this extension was not installed, Magento could not load products correctly.